# How to check out and apply java patches from eclipse git repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, patch, tortoisegit

I found a patch, which solves a issue, I run into.
This Patch is hosted on a [GIT repository](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/8163/)

On Windows I tried to check out the patches by using MsGit, TortoiseGit

```
git fetch git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho refs/changes/63/8163/2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

but Git complained about missing repository.

**Questions**:

- is there a tutorial about checking out those Eclipse repositories?
- how would I apply this Eclipe patch, when I checked it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone the repository first. Start with git clone url_ to_repository

You can find more information here : http://git-scm.com/documentation

I recommend to read this first before you use git with your existing code.

Here is also a good starting point : http://gitref.org/creating/

Comment: Yeah, thnx, but which of the code, I provided - is the git repository? As I saied - I tried to fetch the repository and failed.

Comment: http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/ is the url of the repository and git checkout switches to the master branch

Comment: Getting : fatal: 'git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git ' does not appear to be a git repository. Is it because I am using the wrong syntax, or is the repo incomatible?

Comment: Use git clone http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/ and then git checkout ref/changes/63/8163/2 this should checkout the commit were the code is where you are interested in.

Comment: Thnx, I guess, the repository is just broken. It doe not answer, I get "fatal: unable to connect to git.eclipse.org" on `git clone git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git`

Comment: sorry forgot http:// --- try git clone http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! I successfully checked it out. Can you tell me more about the `refs/changes/63/8163/2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` part? is it a relative path inside the repository? i can not find this inside of the file strucure i just checked out!

Comment: I looked in the repo.I can't find the commit where the patch is located. Perhaps it is deleted ?

Comment: The Repository I got from here(https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/8163/), there patches seems to be available from web... Dont know why they are not available through GIT..